# When save an Excel to csv, the seconds automatically become 0?

Tags: excel, csv, date, time, seconds

I am trying to save an Excel file with date time as a csv file. Here is the date and time in the Excel:

[image]

You can see the seconds are there although they are not shown in the cells. But when I save it as csv using:

[image]

You can see that the seconds are still there, but they all become 00.

[image]

So I actually lose the seconds. How to keep them?